# How to add Web API to Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 without Web API component, I want to add it to my VS (not to a project), how do I do that?

I looked for it in the 'new project section' tried to get it from tools\ get tools and features and to get it from Extensions and updates - got nothing.. what am I missing ?

Comment: Question is unclear: ASP.NET WebAPI is always added to a project (possibly on creation). Adding to VS itself makes no sense. Please rephrase, or better, add why you are trying to add web api to VS?

Comment: I think there was a problem in the installation... and now I don't have it in my vs... should I reinstall it?

Comment: No idea. You need to make your question clwar which means concrete details not the result of your speculation.

Comment: I'll explain it again I have vs (2017)| without option of adding web. api How do I add it to my vs ? that's the problem, please help.

Comment: Have you run the installer to modify which workloads/components are included in your installation? It is all within the "ASP.NET and Web Development" workload.